# the analysis result not being published with 4.1.1 using ANT Task

Tags: java, sonar-runner, sonarqube

I have just upgraded to Sonar4.1.1 and the same project is not being published properly. I am not able to see the data on the dashboard. however when i tried to publish as a new project the project got created successfully with no data.

```
Logs are here
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:40.869 INFO  - 0 files indexed
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:40.893 INFO  - Loading technical debt model...
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:42.036 INFO  - Loading technical debt model done: 1143 ms
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:42.066 DEBUG - ooo Using Connection [jdbc:mysql://qualityhub.clientname.com:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8, UserName=sonarqube@delvmecomendperf6.clientname.com, MySQL Connector Java]
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:42.072 DEBUG - ==>  Preparing: select * from projects where id=?
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:42.105 DEBUG - ==> Parameters: 458(Long)
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:42.130 DEBUG - ooo Using Connection [jdbc:mysql://qualityhub.clientname.com:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8, UserName=sonarqube@delvmecomendperf6.clientname.com, MySQL Connector Java]
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:42.131 DEBUG - ==>  Preparing: update projects set name=?, long_name=?, description=?, scope=?, qualifier=?, kee=?, language=?, root_id=?, copy_resource_id=?, person_id=?, enabled=? where id=?
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:42.132 DEBUG - ==> Parameters: company_ecommerce1(String), company_ecommerce1(String), (String), PRJ(String), TRK(String), company:ecommerce1(String), java(String), null, null, null, true(Boolean), 458(Long)
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:42.140 INFO  - Configure Maven plugins
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:42.692 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2014-02-06)
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:42.715 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2014-01-07, analysis of 2014-02-06 22:38:10.0)
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.927 DEBUG - Initializers :
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.928 INFO  - Base dir: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/scripts
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.928 INFO  - Working dir: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/qa/sonar_temp
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.928 INFO  - Source dirs: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/bin/custom/companyweb/src, /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/bin/custom/companyweb/web/src, /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/bin/custom/accountmanagement/src, /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/bin/custom/companyinboundintegrations/src, /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/bin/custom/companyplatform/src, /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/bin/custom/endeca/src, /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/bin/custom/endecaserver/src, /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/bin/custom/companyoutboundintegrations/src, /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/bin/custom/hybrisframework/src, /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/bin/custom/companycmscockpit/src, /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/bin/custom/lbcmscockpit/src
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.929 INFO  - Test dirs: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/bin/custom/companyweb/testsrc, /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/bin/custom/companyweb/web/testsrc, /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/bin/custom/accountmanagement/testsrc, /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/bin/custom/companyinboundintegrations/testsrc, /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/bin/custom/companyplatform/testsrc, /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/bin/custom/companyoutboundintegrations/testsrc, /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/bin/custom/hybrisframework/testsrc, /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/bin/custom/companycmscockpit/testsrc, /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/bin/custom/lbcmscockpit/testsrc
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.929 INFO  - Binary dirs: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/bin/custom
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.929 WARN  - Source encoding is platform dependent (UTF-8), default locale: en_US
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.943 INFO  - Trying to guess scm provider from project layout...
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.943 DEBUG - Search for: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/scripts/.git
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.944 DEBUG - Search for: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/scripts/.hg
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.944 DEBUG - Search for: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/.git
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.944 DEBUG - Search for: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/.hg
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.944 DEBUG - Search for: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/.git
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.945 DEBUG - Search for: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/.hg
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.945 DEBUG - Search for: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/.git
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.945 DEBUG - Search for: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/.hg
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.945 DEBUG - Search for: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/.git
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.945 DEBUG - Search for: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/.hg
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.945 DEBUG - Search for: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/.git
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.945 DEBUG - Search for: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/.hg
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.946 DEBUG - Search for: /opt/app/ci/.git
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.946 DEBUG - Search for: /opt/app/ci/.hg
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.946 DEBUG - Search for: /opt/app/.git
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.946 DEBUG - Search for: /opt/app/.hg
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.946 DEBUG - Search for: /opt/.git
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.946 DEBUG - Search for: /opt/.hg
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.946 DEBUG - Search for: /.git
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.946 DEBUG - Search for: /.hg
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.947 INFO  - Didn't find which SCM provider is used. Fallback on configuration
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.947 WARN  - SCM URL must not be blank. SCM Stats Plugin will not run.Please check the parameter SCM URL or the <scm> section of Maven pom.
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.955 DEBUG - Sensors : JavaSourceImporter -> JavaSquidSensor -> ScmActivitySensor -> CpdSensor -> SurefireSensor -> ResourceToFileMapper -> org.sonar.plugins.thucydides.ThucydidesSensor@c184a81 -> InitialOpenIssuesSensor -> ProfileSensor -> ProfileEventsSensor -> ProjectLinksSensor -> VersionEventsSensor -> FileHashSensor
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.955 INFO  - Sensor JavaSourceImporter...
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.956 INFO  - Sensor JavaSourceImporter done: 1 ms
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.956 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.957 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 1 ms
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.957 INFO  - Sensor ScmActivitySensor...
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.958 INFO  - Trying to guess scm provider from project layout...
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.959 DEBUG - Search for: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/scripts/.svn
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.959 INFO  - Found SCM type: svn
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.961 INFO  - Retrieve SCM blame information with encoding UTF-8...
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.961 WARN  - SCM Activity Plugin is configured to use more threads than actually available on this machine.
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.964 INFO  - Retrieve SCM blame information with encoding UTF-8 done: 3 ms
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.964 INFO  - Sensor ScmActivitySensor done: 7 ms
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.965 INFO  - Sensor CpdSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.965 INFO  - SonarEngine is used
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.966 INFO  - Sensor CpdSensor done: 1 ms
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.967 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.968 INFO  - parsing /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/qa/sonar_temp/build/surefire-reports
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.969 WARN  - Reports path not found: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/qa/sonar_temp/build/surefire-reports
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.972 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor done: 5 ms
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.973 INFO  - Sensor ResourceToFileMapper...
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.973 INFO  - Sensor ResourceToFileMapper done: 0 ms
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.974 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.thucydides.ThucydidesSensor@c184a81...
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.974 WARN  - Thucydides reports not found in /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/scripts/target/site/thucydides
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.974 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.thucydides.ThucydidesSensor@c184a81 done: 0 ms
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.975 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.996 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 21 ms
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.996 INFO  - Sensor ProfileSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:46.198 INFO  - Sensor ProfileSensor done: 2202 ms
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:46.198 INFO  - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:46.255 INFO  - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 57 ms
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:46.255 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:46.286 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 31 ms
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:46.287 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:46.343 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 56 ms
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:46.343 INFO  - Sensor FileHashSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:46.344 INFO  - Sensor FileHashSensor done: 1 ms
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:46.485 DEBUG - Updating semaphore batch-company:ecommerce1
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.038 INFO  - Execute decorators...
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.039 DEBUG - Decorators: ManualMeasureDecorator -> TaglistDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.taglist.TaglistDistributionDecorator@f631ab6 -> SumDuplicationsDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.doxygen.DoxygenDecorator@126e4ecd -> org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.ClassesDecorator@7f77e2f -> org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.FunctionsDecorator@97d43bf -> org.sonar.plugins.uselesscodetracker.decorator.TempMethodLinesDecorator@3eb6cddb -> org.sonar.plugins.uselesscodetracker.decorator.DuplicationsDecorator@7233bb11 -> org.sonar.plugins.uselesscodetracker.decorator.DeadCodeDecorator@223e93aa -> org.sonar.issuesreport.tree.ResourceTree@7eeab576 -> org.sonar.plugins.toxicity.ToxicityChartDecorator@632f9712 -> UnitTestDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.core.security.ApplyProjectRolesDecorator@121b7c21 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.DirectoriesDecorator@54174e5 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.FilesDecorator@c616915 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.TimeMachineConfigurationPersister@7f6fa3f -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewCoverageFileAnalyzer@4f39e80c -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewItCoverageFileAnalyzer@62b19476 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewOverallCoverageFileAnalyzer@788a0198 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewCoverageAggregator@2c6edffb -> org.sonar.plugins.design.batch.ProjectDsmDecorator@67a7422e -> FileTangleIndexDecorator -> FileDecorator -> FileAuthorsDecorator -> RatingFileDistributionBuilder -> f(lines) -> f(generated_lines) -> f(ncloc) -> f(generated_ncloc) -> f(classes) -> f(packages) -> f(functions) -> f(accessors) -> f(statements) -> f(public_api) -> f(comment_lines) -> f(comment_blank_lines) -> f(public_undocumented_api) -> f(commented_out_code_lines) -> f(complexity) -> f(complexity_in_classes) -> f(complexity_in_functions) -> f(class_complexity_distribution) -> f(lines_to_cover) -> f(uncovered_lines) -> f(conditions_to_cover) -> f(uncovered_conditions) -> f(it_lines_to_cover) -> f(it_uncovered_lines) -> f(it_conditions_to_cover) -> f(it_uncovered_conditions) -> f(overall_lines_to_cover) -> f(overall_uncovered_lines) -> f(overall_conditions_to_cover) -> f(overall_uncovered_conditions) -> f(rfc) -> f(package_cycles) -> f(package_tangles) -> f(package_feedback_edges) -> f(package_edges_weight) -> f(count_asserts) -> f(eloc) -> f(new_lines_to_cover) -> f(new_uncovered_lines) -> f(new_conditions_to_cover) -> f(new_uncovered_conditions) -> f(new_it_lines_to_cover) -> f(new_it_uncovered_lines) -> f(new_it_conditions_to_cover) -> f(new_it_uncovered_conditions) -> f(new_overall_lines_to_cover) -> f(new_overall_uncovered_lines) -> f(new_overall_conditions_to_cover) -> f(new_overall_uncovered_conditions) -> f(sqale_rating_file_distribution) -> org.sonar.plugins.cpd.decorators.DuplicationDensityDecorator@26838573 -> org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.ChidamberKemererDistributionBuilder@513f9590 -> org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.FileComplexityDistributionDecorator@25744a9c -> org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.FunctionComplexityDistributionBuilder@75ce5af9 -> org.sonar.plugins.sigmm.MMDistributionDecorator@7efaa9e2 -> org.sonar.plugins.secrules.SecurityRulesDecorator@816fc8b -> CommentDensityDecorator -> PackageTangleIndexDecorator -> f(file_complexity) -> f(class_complexity) -> f(function_complexity) -> f(assert_per_test) -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.CoverageDecorator@36fb39f6 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.LineCoverageDecorator@279a61ad -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.BranchCoverageDecorator@882b92b -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItLineCoverageDecorator@44929d0b -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItCoverageDecorator@75846058 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItBranchCoverageDecorator@45d16dae -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallLineCoverageDecorator@3877de51 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallCoverageDecorator@45a4b4cd -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallBranchCoverageDecorator@405a2273 -> f(function_complexity_distribution) -> f(file_complexity_distribution) -> f(rfc_distribution) -> f(lcom4_distribution) -> org.sonar.plugins.abacus.AbacusDecorator@4ae54c6 -> org.sonar.plugins.sigmm.MMDecorator@3a508f76 -> Sonar common rules engine -> org.sonar.plugins.taglist.ViolationsDecorator@3e4aba6a -> org.sonar.plugins.uselesscodetracker.decorator.ViolationsDecorator@420d3967 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.IssueTrackingDecorator@4967519d -> org.sonar.plugins.uselesscodetracker.decorator.TotalDecorator@53850507 -> CountUnresolvedIssuesDecorator -> CountFalsePositivesDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.core.technicaldebt.TechnicalDebtDecorator@7798ce82 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.technicaldebt.NewTechnicalDebtDecorator@511df625 -> CommitterViolationMetricsDecorator -> CommitterNewViolationsDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.WeightedIssuesDecorator@97c2b3f -> CommitterDefaultMetricsDecorator -> SQALE measure decorator -> SQALE rating decorator -> ViolationDensityDecorator -> IssuesDensityDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.TendencyDecorator@1bf712df -> VariationDecorator
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.060 INFO  - Saving metrics for: company:ecommerce1 project.
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.094 INFO  - Metrics saved successfully.
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.191 DEBUG - Retrieved 0 issues for resource company_ecommerce1
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.196 DEBUG - Retrieved 0 issues for resource company_ecommerce1
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.384 DEBUG - Decorator time:
[sonar:sonar] ManualMeasureDecorator: 9ms
[sonar:sonar] TaglistDecorator: 3ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.taglist.TaglistDistributionDecorator@f631ab6: 1ms
[sonar:sonar] SumDuplicationsDecorator: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.doxygen.DoxygenDecorator@126e4ecd: 3ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.ClassesDecorator@7f77e2f: 1ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.FunctionsDecorator@97d43bf: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.uselesscodetracker.decorator.TempMethodLinesDecorator@3eb6cddb: 2ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.uselesscodetracker.decorator.DuplicationsDecorator@7233bb11: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.uselesscodetracker.decorator.DeadCodeDecorator@223e93aa: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.issuesreport.tree.ResourceTree@7eeab576: 1ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.toxicity.ToxicityChartDecorator@632f9712: 34ms
[sonar:sonar] UnitTestDecorator: 1ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.security.ApplyProjectRolesDecorator@121b7c21: 8ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.DirectoriesDecorator@54174e5: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.FilesDecorator@c616915: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.TimeMachineConfigurationPersister@7f6fa3f: 17ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewCoverageFileAnalyzer@4f39e80c: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewItCoverageFileAnalyzer@62b19476: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewOverallCoverageFileAnalyzer@788a0198: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewCoverageAggregator@2c6edffb: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.design.batch.ProjectDsmDecorator@67a7422e: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] FileTangleIndexDecorator: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] FileDecorator: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] FileAuthorsDecorator: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] RatingFileDistributionBuilder: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(lines): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(generated_lines): 1ms
[sonar:sonar] f(ncloc): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(generated_ncloc): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(classes): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(packages): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(functions): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(accessors): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(statements): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(public_api): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(comment_lines): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(comment_blank_lines): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(public_undocumented_api): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(commented_out_code_lines): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(complexity): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(complexity_in_classes): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(complexity_in_functions): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(class_complexity_distribution): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(lines_to_cover): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(uncovered_lines): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(conditions_to_cover): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(uncovered_conditions): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(it_lines_to_cover): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(it_uncovered_lines): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(it_conditions_to_cover): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(it_uncovered_conditions): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(overall_lines_to_cover): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(overall_uncovered_lines): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(overall_conditions_to_cover): 1ms
[sonar:sonar] f(overall_uncovered_conditions): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(rfc): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(package_cycles): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(package_tangles): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(package_feedback_edges): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(package_edges_weight): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(count_asserts): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(eloc): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(new_lines_to_cover): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(new_uncovered_lines): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(new_conditions_to_cover): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(new_uncovered_conditions): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(new_it_lines_to_cover): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(new_it_uncovered_lines): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(new_it_conditions_to_cover): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(new_it_uncovered_conditions): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(new_overall_lines_to_cover): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(new_overall_uncovered_lines): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(new_overall_conditions_to_cover): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(new_overall_uncovered_conditions): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(sqale_rating_file_distribution): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.cpd.decorators.DuplicationDensityDecorator@26838573: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.ChidamberKemererDistributionBuilder@513f9590: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.FileComplexityDistributionDecorator@25744a9c: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.FunctionComplexityDistributionBuilder@75ce5af9: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.sigmm.MMDistributionDecorator@7efaa9e2: 6ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.secrules.SecurityRulesDecorator@816fc8b: 10ms
[sonar:sonar] CommentDensityDecorator: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] PackageTangleIndexDecorator: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(file_complexity): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(class_complexity): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(function_complexity): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(assert_per_test): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.CoverageDecorator@36fb39f6: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.LineCoverageDecorator@279a61ad: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.BranchCoverageDecorator@882b92b: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItLineCoverageDecorator@44929d0b: 1ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItCoverageDecorator@75846058: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItBranchCoverageDecorator@45d16dae: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallLineCoverageDecorator@3877de51: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallCoverageDecorator@45a4b4cd: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallBranchCoverageDecorator@405a2273: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(function_complexity_distribution): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(file_complexity_distribution): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(rfc_distribution): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] f(lcom4_distribution): 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.abacus.AbacusDecorator@4ae54c6: 1ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.sigmm.MMDecorator@3a508f76: 4ms
[sonar:sonar] Sonar common rules engine: 1ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.taglist.ViolationsDecorator@3e4aba6a: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.uselesscodetracker.decorator.ViolationsDecorator@420d3967: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.IssueTrackingDecorator@4967519d: 12ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.uselesscodetracker.decorator.TotalDecorator@53850507: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] CountUnresolvedIssuesDecorator: 11ms
[sonar:sonar] CountFalsePositivesDecorator: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.technicaldebt.TechnicalDebtDecorator@7798ce82: 17ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.technicaldebt.NewTechnicalDebtDecorator@511df625: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] CommitterViolationMetricsDecorator: 5ms
[sonar:sonar] CommitterNewViolationsDecorator: 2ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.WeightedIssuesDecorator@97c2b3f: 2ms
[sonar:sonar] CommitterDefaultMetricsDecorator: 14ms
[sonar:sonar] SQALE measure decorator: 26ms
[sonar:sonar] SQALE rating decorator: 2ms
[sonar:sonar] ViolationDensityDecorator: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] IssuesDensityDecorator: 0ms
[sonar:sonar] org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.TendencyDecorator@1bf712df: 105ms
[sonar:sonar] VariationDecorator: 33ms
[sonar:sonar]
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.395 DEBUG - 70 measures to dump
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.591 INFO  - Store results in database
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.592 DEBUG - Execute org.sonar.batch.index.ComponentDataPersister
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.597 DEBUG - Execute org.sonar.batch.issue.IssuePersister
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.602 DEBUG - Execute org.sonar.batch.phases.GraphPersister
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.679 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://qualityhub.clientname.com/dashboard/index/company:ecommerce1
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.679 DEBUG - Evict preview database
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.680 DEBUG - Download: http://qualityhub.clientname.com/batch_bootstrap/evict?project=458 (no proxy)
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.764 DEBUG - Post-jobs : org.sonar.plugins.doxygen.DoxygenPostJob@885e019 -> org.sonar.issuesreport.ReportJob@d3b8dae -> org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob@40d2a14b -> org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob@445b642c -> org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob@4c0da7c3 -> org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.AlertBreaker@14811a37 -> org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.ForbiddenConfigurationBreaker@27e01b65
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.764 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.doxygen.DoxygenPostJob
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.766 ERROR - The global property 'sonar.doxygen.deploymentPath' is not set. Set it in SONAR and run another analysis.
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.781 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.issuesreport.ReportJob
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.781 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.782 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.851 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.869 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2014-01-09 and 2014-02-05
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.871 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per week between 2013-02-07 and 2014-01-09
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.871 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per month between 2009-02-12 and 2013-02-07
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.871 INFO  - -> Delete data prior to: 2009-02-12
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.874 DEBUG - ooo Using Connection [jdbc:mysql://qualityhub.clientname.com:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8, UserName=sonarqube@delvmecomendperf6.clientname.com, MySQL Connector Java]
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.874 DEBUG - ==>  Preparing: select * from projects where id=?
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.874 DEBUG - ==> Parameters: 458(Long)
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.879 DEBUG - ooo Using Connection [jdbc:mysql://qualityhub.clientname.com:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8, UserName=sonarqube@delvmecomendperf6.clientname.com, MySQL Connector Java]
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.879 DEBUG - ==>  Preparing: select * from projects where scope='PRJ' and root_id=?
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.880 DEBUG - ==> Parameters: 458(Long)
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.882 INFO  - -> Clean company_ecommerce1 [id=458]
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:48.891 INFO  - <- Clean snapshot 2308
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:49.143 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.AlertBreaker
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:49.144 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.ForbiddenConfigurationBreaker
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:49.145 DEBUG - Release semaphore on project : org.sonar.api.resources.Project@43cda81e[id=458,key=company:ecommerce1,qualifier=TRK], with key batch-company:ecommerce1
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:52.044 WARN  - [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 2,825ms last 8 cycles average is 353ms
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:52.065 DEBUG - To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] has been forcibly deregistered

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 minute 24 seconds
[scripts] $ /opt/app/ci/ant/ant/bin/ant -file build.xml -Dproject.home=/opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace -Duseconfig=CI dist
Buildfile: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/scripts/build.xml

install.prepare:

install.create.install:
     [echo] Generating install script from localextensions
     [xslt] Processing /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/hybris/config/localextensions.xml to /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/scripts/install.xml
     [xslt] Loading stylesheet /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/scripts/install.xsl

install.prepare:

install.platform.check.available:

install.platform.check.uptodate:

install.platform.unzip:

install.platform:
     [copy] Warning: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/patches/platform does not exist.

install.all:

install.install:

install.prepare:

install.platform.check.available:

install.platform.check.uptodate:

install.platform.unzip:

install.platform:
     [copy] Warning: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/patches/platform does not exist.
```

Comment: There's a lot of log data there. Is any of it relevant? If you're not sure, delete it.

Comment: Im seeing the same issue. SCM URL must not be blank. When I go see for any field for sonar.scm.url, there is NO such entry in SCM Activity plugin. I have compatible plugins with Sonar's version. Tried uninstalling/installing it again, still getting the error. I'm wondering what if I create a sonar-project.properties file and put the entry sonar.scm.url=xxx there.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue with sonar

Answer (score 0):

You should check you warning messages.

It says several times that the reports were not found. Without any reports found there aren't any results on SonarQube. Try to find the reason why you project is not analysed by this "Code analyse tools".

Maybe your tools are not up to date? Or the language of the project is another one then the selected of SonarQube (SonarQube selected "?" as it seems or you changed it for this post to a questionmark).

here is an example of your own message:

```
Sensor SurefireSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.968 INFO  - parsing /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/qa/sonar_temp/build/surefire-reports
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.969 WARN  - Reports path not found: /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/qa/sonar_temp/build/surefire-reports
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.972 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor done: 5 ms
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.973 INFO  - Sensor ResourceToFileMapper...
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.973 INFO  - Sensor ResourceToFileMapper done: 0 ms
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.974 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.thucydides.ThucydidesSensor@c184a81...
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.974 WARN  - Thucydides reports not found in /opt/app/ci/jenkins/home/jobs/company-ci-build_trunk/workspace/scripts/target/site/thucydides
[sonar:sonar] 23:28:43.974 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.thucydides.ThucydidesSensor@c184a81 done: 0 ms
```